# Tomcat or Apache container modifies my response

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I have a web application in which there are filters , servlets and error handling defined in web.xml

In error handling I define the servlet which needs to take care of error handling.

The error handler servlet has access to request and response variable

It sets http status 404 in response.

and also sets my custom error page in the response output stream.

And that's it.

But when the container ( I will describe my container in a little while) returns the response to the browser, the browser displays its own 404 page instead of my custom error page.

In the chrome browser-> developer tools I see the 404 status

If I make the following change: error page servlet sets http status 200 in response

I get my error page.
In the chrome browser-> developer tools I see the 200 status

Now lets go back a bit, this application is working in PRODUCTION in a different container with slight modification in code (some less logging) . And there error page servlet sets 404 in response.(custom error page is displayed)

Container :
    My application (both of them ) has a setup in which it runs from apache AND tomcat container.
    Apache is used to serve static content
    Tomcat for the dynamic content.

The difference between these two container is just the version of the Tomcat and apache and difference in the Redhat version they use.

Question :
How do i debug this issue. How come Tomcat / Apache is modifying the output stream that I set. Or has apache/ tomcat has completely modified my response.

My error page servlet has all the logging and looks good but it seems the response is modified by the container.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data flow is the following :

```
browser --> apache --> tomcat
```

then apache can have a configuration to serve 404 response code. 
Please confirm that your request goes though apache and post here the configuration.

This article may help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache

Comment: We had some figuration in which we need to modify apache properties : proxyErrorOverride